# Translate mySQL query to Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm not able to write a Postgres query. I always get an error or get wrong results. I try to compare counts between today and yesterday.

This `MySQL` query which is working fine:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(crh.date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS name,
    DATE_FORMAT(crh.date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS nameGroup,
    COUNT(crh.id) AS turnover,
    crh_.name AS nameChr,
    crh_.nameGroup AS nameGroupChr,
    crh_.turnover AS turnoverChr
FROM
    camera_reports_history AS crh
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(crh_.date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS name,
        DATE_FORMAT(crh_.date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS nameGroup,
        COUNT(crh_.id) AS turnover
    FROM
        camera_reports_history AS crh_
    WHERE
        crh_.date >= '2018-07-09 00:00:00' AND crh_.date <= '2018-07-20 14:02:22'
    GROUP BY
        nameGroup
) AS crh_
ON
    crh_.nameGroup = DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(crh.date, 1),
    '%Y-%m-%d')
WHERE
    crh.date >= '2018-07-10 00:00:00' AND crh.date <= '2018-07-20 14:02:22'
GROUP BY
    nameGroup
```

Result:

```
"10-07-2018","2018-07-10","418","09-07-2018","2018-07-09","581"
"11-07-2018","2018-07-11","389","10-07-2018","2018-07-10","418"
"12-07-2018","2018-07-12","453","11-07-2018","2018-07-11","389"
"13-07-2018","2018-07-13","401","12-07-2018","2018-07-12","453"
...
```

My `PostgreSQL` query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    to_char(crh."date", 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS name,
    to_char(crh."date", 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS nameGroup,
    COUNT(crh.id) AS turnover,
    crh_.name AS nameChr,
    crh_.nameGroup AS nameGroupChr,
    crh_.turnover AS turnoverChr
FROM
    camera_reports_history AS crh
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT to_char(crh_."date", 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS name,
        to_char(crh_."date", 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS nameGroup,
        COUNT(crh_.id) AS turnover
    FROM
        camera_reports_history AS crh_
    WHERE
        crh_.date >= '2018-07-09 00:00:00' AND crh_.date <= '2018-07-20 14:02:22'
    GROUP BY
        nameGroup,
        name
    ORDER BY
        nameGroup
) AS crh_
ON
    crh_.nameGroup = to_char(
        crh."date" - INTERVAL '1 day',
        'YYYY-MM-DD'
    )
WHERE
    crh.date >= '2018-07-10 00:00:00' AND crh.date <= '2018-07-20 14:02:22'
GROUP BY
    nameGroup,
    name
ORDER BY
    nameGroup
```

errors:

```
ERROR: column `crh.date` must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

if I insert necessary columns:

```
GROUP BY nameGroup, name, date, crh_.nameGroup, crh_.name, crh_.turnover
```

I will get useless results.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: "Useless results" is not very much information. Can you describe the difference with a sample?

Comment: i get all `crh."date"` results and not grouped by `nameGroup`.
each query `SELECT` and `LEFT JOIN` are working fine, but together i have problems

Comment: That should go away if you `GROUP BY name, namegroup`. The bigger problem are the `crh_.*` values in the select list - for each group, which of these values should appera in the result?

Comment: where do you see `crh_.*` in the select list? if i group `crh.date` (to solve the error) i get all dates ungrouped in the result.

Comment: Right, so `GROUP BY name, namegroup`. I was talking about `crh_.name` and the like.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON(nameGroup) 
    to_char(crh."date", 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS name,
    to_char(crh."date", 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS nameGroup,
    crh__.turnover AS turnover,
    crh_.name AS nameChr,
    crh_.nameGroup AS nameGroupChr,
    crh_.turnover AS turnoverChr
FROM
    camera_reports_history AS crh
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT 
        to_char(crh__."date", 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS nameGroup__,
        COUNT(crh__.id) AS turnover
    FROM
        camera_reports_history AS crh__
    WHERE
        crh__.date >= '2018-07-10 00:00:00' AND crh__.date <= '2018-07-20 14:02:22'
    GROUP BY
        nameGroup__
) AS crh__ ON crh__.nameGroup__ = to_char((crh."date"), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT to_char(crh_."date", 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS name,
        to_char(crh_."date", 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS nameGroup,
        COUNT(crh_.id) AS turnover
    FROM
        camera_reports_history AS crh_
    WHERE
        crh_.date >= '2018-07-09 00:00:00' AND crh_.date <= '2018-07-20 14:02:22'
    GROUP BY
        nameGroup,
        name
    ORDER BY
        nameGroup
) AS crh_ ON crh_.nameGroup = to_char((crh."date" - INTERVAL '1 day'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
WHERE
    crh.date >= '2018-07-10 00:00:00' AND crh.date <= '2018-07-20 14:02:22'
GROUP BY
    nameGroup,
    name,
    crh.date,
    crh__.turnover,
    crh_.nameGroup,
    crh_.name,
    crh_.turnover
ORDER BY
    nameGroup
```

I make a 2nd `LEFT JOIN` to count the results and use `DISTINCT ON(nameGroup)` on the main `SELECT`.

I think it's not a perfect query. but my problem is solved at this moment.
Please feel free to optimate this query.

Answer (score -1):

Transaction blocks work well in postgresql, so instead of a complex compound statement that attempts to sort, join, group and filter all at once, you can use temporary tables.  This allows you to break the steps up into multiple simple statements and store intermediate data in temp tables that disappear at the end of the transaction block.

I think you'll find this method a lot easier to debug.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.